# windows batch file checking power plug with Battery.PowerOnline returns always FALSE

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tablet

I did on a lot of windows 10 tablets a shutdown check when the power in the room switched off. Now I tried to update a view dell 8.1 tablets, but the Battery.PowerOnline returns always false. Any ideas?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryStatus              Get PowerOnline^,RemainingCapacity /Format:list ^| FIND "="') DO SET Battery.%%A
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryRuntime             Get EstimatedRuntime               /Format:list ^| FIND "="') DO SET Battery.%%A
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryFullChargedCapacity Get FullChargedCapacity            /Format:list ^| FIND "="') DO SET Battery.%%A

IF /I "%Battery.PowerOnline%"=="TRUE" (
    SET doShutDown=0
) ELSE (
    SET doShutDown=1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `set Battery.%%A` which will not set anything to be honest, also, you never defined `%Battery.PowerOnline%` variable, so it will never return true. Do we really need to check each status? Only the last `set` from your three commands will keep the variable value, so rather check the main poweronline value and do something from there. Notice how I set the variables:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryStatus Get PowerOnline /Format:list ^| FIND "PowerOnline"') DO SET "Battery=%%A" & goto :verify

:verify
if /I "%Battery%"=="PowerOnline=TRUE" (
    set doShutDown=0
) else (
    set doShutDown=1
)
```

Comment: the same with your script, the tablet returns always False.

Comment: after the for loop, add `echo %Battery%` and send me exactly what is prints to screen

Comment: PowerOnline=FALSE, the problem is the tablet, not the script.

Comment: ok, so there will be 2 settings. Let me make a change to the script quick.

Comment: Changed, please test it now.

Comment: There are 2 values. The for loop sets each but can only carry the value for the last item in the loop so we simply set the first and exit the loop to maintain the value.